# Determine what javascript is overwriting option text on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, magento2

Chrome has a feature as did firebug before it went defunct to break on an element's changes.  Chrome however, only breaks on 3 types of changes and Firebug no longer works on new versions of Firefox and the tool to replace doesn't have the ability to break on changes to an element.

I have tried all three break on events for chrome and none enter the debugger.  I have a select list like:

```
<select id="someid">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="12"> Some Text with bad formatting and <span>in it for some reason</span>
    <option value="13"> Other text &nbsp; with <span>etc</span> in it</option>
 </select>
```

What I have found happens is that some JS on load will replace all the bad option text with valid html after load.  Why does magento2 do this?  I don't know.  But it makes it a pain for me and is likely tied to a core feature as the spans have ids to products and more in it.

I append text to the options but it gets removed by this other replace procedure.  I ended up writing setTimeout to check every 1000ms if the newer option text is there, and add my changes.  But it's not a good fix it's a work around that is prone to break for a multitude of reasons, and slow besides.

My question is, in this gigantic huge program of software I never wrote how can I easily find what arbitrary javascript is changing the option text on load?  Chrome won't persist on load, and even if I quickfinger Mcgee it and hit f8 to pause loading just as it starts, then find the element, then set it to break on changes, it doesn't actually break.

So I tried Mutation Observers, but then found out via another stack overflow answer to someone else's question, that you can never have the call stack visible using mutation observers.  So now I'm looking at watch(), but I doubt it will solve my issue either?

Why isn't breaking on changes to element or it's children or it's text from JS a default easy to use feature this is a CONSTANT issue in development to find out which chunk of code in thousands and thousands of lines is actually causing a behavior you don't want, or you wish to run other javascript after it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to comment, but based on what you said:

> What I have found happens is that some JS on load will replace all the bad option text with valid html after load. Why does magento2 do this?

i was thinking if magento doesn't have a function to show raw input ? maybe it's the root of your problems...

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/569/how-to-escape-output-data